# Custom listview with button and json

Tags: java, json, button, android-listview, buttonclick

CustomListAdapter.java

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Patient> patientItems;
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Patient> movieItems) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.patientItems = movieItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return patientItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return patientItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    Button viewBtn = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.view_btn);

    // getting data for the row
    Patient m = patientItems.get(position);

    // thumbnail image
    thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);

    // title
    title.setText(m.getTitle());
    viewBtn.setTag(position);
    viewBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int tag = (Integer) v.getTag();
            switch (tag) {
                case 0:
                    TextView c = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
                    String item = c.getText().toString();
                    Log.d("id", item);
                    //Toast.makeText(PatientList.this, "row " + item  + " was pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;

                case 1:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

}
```

PatientList.java

```
public class PatientList extends FragmentActivity implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {
// Log tag
private static final String TAG = PatientList.class.getSimpleName();
// initially offset will be 0, later will be updated while parsing the json
private int offSet = 0;

// Movies json url
private static final String url = "http://192.168.0.102/test/apps.php";
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private List<Patient> patientList = new ArrayList<Patient>();
private ListView listView;
private CustomListAdapter adapter;

private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.patientlist_listview);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);

    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, patientList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    // Showing progress dialog before making http request
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();

    // changing action bar color
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#00BBD3")));

    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

    /**
     * Showing Swipe Refresh animation on activity create
     * As animation won't start on onCreate, post runnable is used
     */
    swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                                    fetchPatients();
                                }
                            }
    );

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Click event for single list row
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(PatientList.this, "row " + position + " was pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    TextView c = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
                    String item = c.getText().toString();
                    Log.d("id", item);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    break;
            }

        }

    });


}



/**
 * This method is called when swipe refresh is pulled down
 */
@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    fetchPatients();
}
/**
 * Fetching movies json by making http call
 */
private void fetchPatients() {

    // showing refresh animation before making http call
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

    // Creating volley request obj
    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();
                    Log.d("id", "hi") ;
                    // Parsing json
                    // reset the list
                    patientList.clear();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length();i++) {
                        try {
                            Log.d("id","hi1") ;
                            Log.d("i","i:"+i);

                            Patient patient = new Patient();

                            Log.d("length", "length:" + response.length());
                            JSONObject objid= response.getJSONObject(i);
                            //get id
                            patient.setTitle(objid.getString("id"));

                            JSONObject objimage= response.getJSONObject(++i);
                                        patient.setThumbnailUrl(objimage.getString("image"));                       

                            // adding movie to movies array
                            if(i%2==1)
                            patientList.add(patient);


                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    // stopping swipe refresh
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hidePDialog();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    // stopping swipe refresh
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                }
            });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    hidePDialog();
}

private void hidePDialog() {
    if (pDialog != null) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog = null;
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Patient.java

```
public class Patient {
private String title;

public Patient() {
}

public Patient(String name) {
    this.title = name;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String name) {
    this.title = name;
}


}
```

Error messages

```
01-11 03:16:30.607 25561-25561/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
01-11 03:16:30.636 25561-25569/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
01-11 03:16:30.793 25561-25582/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
01-11 03:16:30.814 25561-25561/? D/Atlas: Validating map...
01-11 03:16:30.907 25561-25582/? D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
01-11 03:16:30.910 25561-25582/? D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
01-11 03:16:30.934 25561-25582/? D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
01-11 03:16:30.985 25561-25582/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-11 03:16:31.037 25561-25582/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
01-11 03:16:31.069 25561-25582/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-11 03:16:31.069 25561-25582/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xf3fcf2e0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
01-11 03:16:31.193 25561-25582/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-11 03:16:31.193 25561-25582/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xf3fcf320, error=EGL_SUCCESS
01-11 03:16:32.099 25561-25561/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley D/PatientList: [{"id":"g"},{"image":"http:\/\/192.168.56.1\/test\/1.png"},{"id":"xd"},{"image":"http:\/\/192.168.56.1\/test\/2.png"},{"id":"hallo"},{"image":"http:\/\/192.168.56.1\/test\/2.png"}]
01-11 03:16:32.134 25561-25561/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley D/id: hi
01-11 03:16:32.134 25561-25561/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley D/id: hi1
01-11 03:16:32.135 25561-25561/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley D/i: i:0
01-11 03:16:32.135 25561-25561/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley D/length: length:6
01-11 03:16:32.136 25561-25561/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley D/id: hi1
01-11 03:16:32.136 25561-25561/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley D/i: i:2
01-11 03:16:32.136 25561-25561/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley D/length: length:6
01-11 03:16:32.136 25561-25561/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley D/id: hi1
01-11 03:16:32.136 25561-25561/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley D/i: i:4
01-11 03:16:32.136 25561-25561/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley D/length: length:6
01-11 03:16:32.347 25561-25569/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.607ms
01-11 03:16:32.556 25561-25574/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 707(71KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(81KB) LOS objects, 39% free, 2MB/3MB, paused 1.361ms total 130.175ms
01-11 03:16:38.118 25561-25561/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-11 03:16:38.118 25561-25561/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley, PID: 25561
                                                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.TextView.getText()' on a null object reference
                                                                                       at info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.adater.CustomListAdapter$1.onClick(CustomListAdapter.java:83)
                                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
01-11 03:17:02.358 25561-25561/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 25561 SIG: 9
```

From the error messages,i knew that it has got the data that i want but i cannot get the data from the title.

I have also checked the tag. Clicking the first row's button gets the number zero.

```
 switch (tag) {
                case 0:
                    TextView c = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
                    String item = c.getText().toString();
                    Log.d("id", item);
                    //Toast.makeText(PatientList.this, "row " + item  + " was pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
```

The line of error code is

```
String item = c.getText().toString();
```

But I cannot get the string item by using the c.getText().toString();. How can I change the code to get the textview's string. Please give me some helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try these i think its working
first you replace viewBtn click listener by viewBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
then
put code in your adapter class

```
private class OnItemClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        private int mPosition;

        OnItemClickListener(int position) {
            mPosition = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
           Patient p=patientItems.get(mPosition);
String Title=p.getTitle();
Log.d("Title at row"+mPosition,Title);
        }
    }
```

Comment: your code not working due to nullPointer execption you find text view inside of button view so generate errors you can use covertView insted of  viewBtn then it works fine

Comment: but why did't  (TextView c = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);) this line of code have errors? It can still the id of the textview from the layout but why did't it get the values?

Comment: you right but button view and textview both are inside of convertview and you use code for find text view inside of button view so your code give errors

Comment: So this means that it still knows that there is a textview but it cannot use it ,right?